# FFmpeg - set a specific frame rate, per frame, for a video file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, refresh-rate

I have a file with 100 frames.

I know to the ms when each frame should be displayed on screen (because of metadata I can pull from the bitstream).

I would like to use FFmpeg to re-encode the file into a new format, and specify the PTS value for EACH frame in the file.

The resulting video file would playback with ms accuracy per frame.

... Is this possible?

I see video files that have variable PTS values - and I can calculate those PTS values using FFProbe, but I don't know a way of writing a file with defined variable PTS values.

Comment: [Method 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37893746/5726027) or [Method 2](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/20590/1871)

Comment: Method 1 looks like an awesome option.  Do you know if there is a windows compiled option anywhere?  I'm not very linux savvy and having an EXE to work from would be really helpful.

Comment: http://www.datafilehost.com/d/166e6993